# How could I use docker to give clients access to multiple applications running on 1 server?

Tags: docker

Lets say I have a server with 200 gigs ram and very fast. I basically want to host an application like rserver which runs through a web interface.

I would like to put each application into a container with a set number of cpu and ram allocated. Each container would be for each student I have.

How would I give each student a http address to use without hardcoding each student to a port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For allocating cpu and ram you have options in `docker run` when creating your containers (see `docker help run`) like `--cpuset-cpus=` or `--memory=`.

For each student having a different http address, this is not going to be straightforward. What we have done for a VM hosting 8 jenkins master services each running in containers and each listening to the 8080 port (in the container) exposed as 808x, is to configure an Apache dispatcher (or nginx) listening only on 443 and, for each 8 DNS names, dispatching to a different container. See the system here: http://www.slideshare.net/cm13/scaling-your-jenkins-master-with-docker/16

For setting up such a system, you would need to have access to a DNS server configuration so as to create a new name for each student. And you would also need to automatize the creation of the Apache vhost configs (which is not very difficult). Then each student with go to https://hishername/ which will launch the application.

I would really advice to also automate the creation of containers, with `docker-compose` or other technology.